# STM32 USB to USB

Tags: c, usb, stm32, hid

I want to design the following project. I have Device (lets say mouse) that i connect to USB HOST of STM32 on other hand i connect USB Device of STM32 to PC (HOST). The idea is to use the STM32F723 something like USB HID BUFFER. The idea is when i disconnect the device(mouse) from STM32, the PC still recognize that HID is connected to it, and this should happening through the STM32.
I have design the first part:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "usb_device.h"
#include "usb_host.h"


#include "usbh_hid.h"
//#include "usbd_hid.h"  // error occurs: HID already been declared. 
#include "stdio.h"

    int main(void)
    {
      HAL_Init();
      SystemClock_Config();
      MX_GPIO_Init();
      MX_UART7_Init();
      MX_USB_HOST_Init();
      MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH,GPIO_PIN_12,GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOH,GPIO_PIN_15,GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOI,GPIO_PIN_10,GPIO_PIN_SET);
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG,GPIO_PIN_8,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      while (1)
      {
        MX_USB_HOST_Process();
    
      }
     
    }
    
        void USBH_HID_EventCallback(USBH_HandleTypeDef *phost)
        {
        if ( USBH_HID_GetDeviceType(phost) == HID_MOUSE)
            {   
                HID_MOUSE_Info_TypeDef *Mouse_Info;
                Mouse_Info = USBH_HID_GetMouseInfo(phost);
                int X_VAL = Mouse_Info -> x;
                int Y_VAL = Mouse_Info -> y;
                if (X_VAL > 127) X_VAL -= 255;
                if (Y_VAL > 127) Y_VAL -= 255;
                
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_7,GPIO_PIN_SET);
                //USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS,Mouse_Info,sizeof(Mouse_Info));
                int len = sprintf (TxBuff, "X=%d ,Y=%d, Button1=%d, Button2=%d, Button3=%d\n", X_VAL,Y_VAL, Mouse_Info -> buttons[0],Mouse_Info ->buttons[1], Mouse_Info -> buttons[2]);
                HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart7,(uint8_t*)TxBuff,len,1000)
                
            }
```

Now i want to design the second part where i should copy the descriptors of the mouse to the STM32_USB_DEVICE_HID and send it to the PC. But i cant do that, also when i include usbd_hid.h error occurs. Any idea how that could be done ?

The board is STM32F723E-DISCO

Comment: Does the STM32F723  chip support being both a host and a device at the same time?  That seems kind of unlikely; both modes of operation probably use the same USB hardware and pins.

Comment: It has two separated USB_OTG peripherals , one FS and one HS it should work.
Actually I made it work kind of.  PC recognize the the STM32 like a HID but mouse is not working properly when i transfer descriptors from the USB host to USB device.

Answer (score -1):

STM32 work just fine like a host i can see that thru UART serial monitor. Next step is to transfer HID Report to the PC and this should happen in Device mode. Any ideas how to transfer.

Below is the struct of the Device attached to the Host(STM32). Now i have to transfer that to the PC.

```
typedef struct _HID_MOUSE_Info
{
  uint8_t              x;
  uint8_t              y;
  uint8_t              buttons[3];
}
HID_MOUSE_Info_TypeDef;
```

i am using that function:

```
USBD_HID_SendReport(&hUsbDeviceFS,Mouse_Info,sizeof(Mouse_Info ));
```

PC recognize STM32 as HID but the data from the mouse x, y, buttons are not transferred properly because mouse is not now working fine.

Comment: It is not answer. Do not use answers as comments. Modify the original question!